# What causes a move assignment operator to not be called?

Tags: c++, c++17, move, move-semantics

I'm working on my own smart pointer and I ran into some weird problems. The move assignment operator was not being called. So I wrote a test class and was able to reproduce the issue. The move assignment operator is not called but a copy assignment occurs (even when there is no copy assignment operator).

This is my test class

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct tag_t {};
constexpr tag_t tag {};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  Foo() noexcept
    : val{} {
    std::cout << "Default construct\n";
  }
  template <typename U>
  Foo(tag_t, const U &val) noexcept
    : val{val} {
    std::cout << "Construct " << val << '\n';
  }
  ~Foo() noexcept {
    std::cout << "Destruct " << val << '\n';
  }

  template <typename U>
  Foo(Foo<U> &&other) noexcept
    : val{std::exchange(other.val, U{})} {
    std::cout << "Move construct " << val << '\n';
  }
  template <typename U>
  Foo &operator=(Foo<U> &&other) noexcept {
    std::cout << "Move assign " << other.val << '\n';
    val = std::exchange(other.val, U{});
    return *this;
  }

  T val;
};
```

These are the tests

```
int main() {
  {
    Foo<int> num;
    std::cout << "Value " << num.val << '\n';
    num = {tag, 5};
    std::cout << "Value " << num.val << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
  {
    Foo<int> num;
    std::cout << "Value " << num.val << '\n';
    num = Foo<int>{tag, 5};
    std::cout << "Value " << num.val << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

After running the tests, I get these results

```
Default construct
Value 0
Construct 5
Destruct 5
Value 5
Destruct 5

Default construct
Value 0
Construct 5
Move assign 5
Destruct 0
Value 5
Destruct 5
```

What baffles me is the output of the first test. The move assignment operator is not called but a copy assignment takes place. This results in `5` being destroyed twice. Not ideal when you're trying to make a smart pointer!

I'm compiling with Apple Clang with optimizations disabled. Can someone explain my observations? Also, how do I ensure that the move assignment operator is called in the first test?

Comment: If your question is concerned only with the first test, perhaps remove the rest and reduce the question to a minimal state, so as not to make it too thick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename U>
Foo &operator=(Foo<U> &&other) noexcept;
```

this cannot be called by `={ }`.

Instead, `Foo& operator=(Foo&&)noexcept` is called.

Template methods are never special member functions.  Explicitly default, delete or implement them.

Comment: So the declared move assignment operator does not override the compiler generated move assignment operator? The compiler generated move assignment operator just moves all of the members and moving an integer is the same as copying.

Comment: @Kerndog73 What he's saying is you have created a templated move operator, which does not override the default creation of a move constructor/move assignment operator pair. Consequently, the default move assignment operator is called. Add a move constructor and the call will fail, as the move assignment operator will no longer be automatically generated. In short, you need to create a *non-templated* move assignment operator to get the functionality you need. A similar move constructor is also probably necessary.

Comment: @Kerndog73 (Technically, the template is [not even considered a move assignment operator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.assign#3)…) Yes, `a = b` always invokes the special member function, which is never a template, and may be compiler-generated if `a` and `b` are expressions of the same type (modulo cv-qualifiers). If that's deleted, the call is illegal. Same goes for c'tor of same type. Simply put, the templates can only be used for conversions, such as assigning `shared_ptr<U>` or `unique_ptr<U,D>` to a `shared_ptr<T>` (provided that `U*` is convertible to `T*`).